# HMAC security - Is the security of the HMAC based on SHA-1 affected by the collisions attacks on SHA-1?

Tags: cryptography, sha1, hashcode, hmac, cryptographic-hash-function

Is the security of the HMAC based on SHA-1 affected by the collisions attacks on SHA-1?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The security implications of HMAC are described in detail in the security section of [the RFC](http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc2104.html). In a nutshell, a very strong attack indeed is required before the security of the HMAC is threatened; the existing collision attacks on SHA-1 certainly don't constitute such. HMAC is specifically designed to make attacks difficult, and ordinary collision attacks won't generally suffice:

> The security of the message
>   authentication mechanism presented
>   here depends on cryptographic
>   properties of the hash function H: the
>   resistance to collision finding
>   (limited to the case where the initial
>   value is secret and random, and where
>   the output of the function is not
>   explicitly available to the attacker),
>   and the message authentication
>   property of the compression function
>   of H when applied to single blocks (in
>   HMAC these blocks are partially
>   unknown to an attacker as they contain
>   the result of the inner H computation
>   and, in particular, cannot be fully
>   chosen by the attacker).

I recommend reading the whole section; it goes into more detail about exactly what attacks *would* suffice to break an HMAC, and just how much effort would be required.

Answer (score 3):

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2889473/when-is-it-safe-to-use-a-broken-hash-function/2894496) for a discussion on the same theme. In a nutshell: collision attacks do not directly harm HMAC. But the existence of collision attacks implies that the compression function on which the hash function is built is not a "random oracle", and this voids the HMAC security proof.

Answer (score -1):

The strongest attack known against HMAC is based on the frequency of
   collisions for the hash function H ("birthday attack") [PV,BCK2], and
   is totally impractical for minimally reasonable hash functions.

As an example, if we consider a hash function like MD5 where the
   output length equals L=16 bytes (128 bits) the attacker needs to
   acquire the correct message authentication tags computed (with the
   *same* secret key K!) on about 2**64 known plaintexts.  This would
   require the processing of at least 2**64 blocks under H, an
   impossible task in any realistic scenario (for a block length of 64
   bytes this would take 250,000 years in a continuous 1Gbps link, and
   without changing the secret key K during all this time).  This attack
   could become realistic only if serious flaws in the collision
   behavior of the function H are discovered (e.g.  collisions found
   after 2**30 messages). Such a discovery would determine the immediate
   replacement of the function H (the effects of such failure would be
   far more severe for the traditional uses of H in the context of
   digital signatures, public key certificates, etc.).

Note: this attack needs to be strongly contrasted with regular
   collision attacks on cryptographic hash functions where no secret key
   is involved and where 2**64 off-line parallelizable (!) operations
   suffice to find collisions.  The latter attack is approaching
   feasibility [VW] ***while the birthday attack on HMAC is totally
   impractical.  (In the above examples, if one uses a hash function
   with, say, 160 bit of output then 2**64 should be replaced by 2**80.)***

A correct implementation of the above construction, the choice of
   random (or cryptographically pseudorandom) keys, a secure key
   exchange mechanism, frequent key refreshments, and good secrecy
   protection of keys are all essential ingredients for the security of
   the integrity verification mechanism provided by HMAC.

Comment: If you're going to extensively quote from RFC2104, the honest thing to do would be to admit as much.

Comment: damn, I found this answer searching for an excerpt of RFC 2104, lolz