# HMAC 256 vs HMAC 512 JWT signature encryption

Tags: http, authentication, encryption, jwt, digital-signature

Is there practical difference between HS256 and HS512 encryption algorithms, or is the additional security from longer key redundant compared to already unbreakable key? Which one should I use to encrypt the JWT token?

Is it even possible to use HS512 encryption with auth0's [java JWT](https://github.com/auth0/java-jwt)?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The algorithm is used to perform a digital signature (not encryption) over the header and payload of the token. If you want to encrypt the token payload, you need to apply the JWE standard (see [RFC](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7519))

> Is there a practical difference between HS256 and HS512 encryption algorithms, or is the additional security from longer key redundant compared to already unbreakable key? Which one should I use to encrypt the JWT token?

HS256 means HMAC-SHA256. The difference with HS512 is the strength of the hash methods themselves. You can take a look at the [keylength.com](https://www.keylength.com/) website and this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18080445/difference-between-hmacsha256-and-hmacsha512). You will see that even SHA-256 has quite a large security margin. What's more, the HMAC algorithm is pretty much oblivious to attacks on the underlying hash algorithm. So even you can use HMAC-SHA1 safely.

> Is it even possible to use HS512 encryption with auth0's java JWT?

I took a look at the code, and it is possible (but not documented).  Use something similar to

```
JWTSigner.Options options = new JWTSigner.Options();
options.setAlgorithm(Algorithm.HS512);
jwtSigner.sign(claims, options);
```

Answer (score 0):

> Is it even possible to use HS512 encryption with auth0's java JWT?

You could do something like this:

```
Jwts.builder()
    .setSubject(username)
    .setIssuedAt(new Date())
    .setExpiration(new Date((new Date()).getTime() + jwtExpirationMs))
    .signWith(SignatureAlgorithm.HS512, jwtSecret)
    .compact();
```

Example taken from here: [link](https://www.bezkoder.com/spring-boot-security-login-jwt/)