# More secure S3 URLs

Tags: encryption, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, sha

I am currently following Amazon's documentation to sign S3 URL's for download. Using hmac-sha1 is good but I want something more secure since there are inherent flaws as of 2010. Also, it is good marketing too to use strong encryption. I *KNOW* that others are using 256-bit encryption when signing their URLs. I too would like to use sha256 or sha512, but it seems like Amazon's docs don't tell you how this is possible. They only reference hmac-sha1 (which I'm currently using w/ succcess).

```
Signature = URL-Encode( Base64( HMAC-SHA1( YourSecretAccessKeyID, UTF-8-Encoding-Of( StringToSign ) ) ) );
```

How would I go about using something more secure?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are inherent flaws to sha-1 but [they don't carry over to hmac-sha-1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3334524/hmac-security-is-the-security-of-the-hmac-based-on-sha-1-affected-by-the-colli?lq=1), so there's no need to worry.

That being said, I actually *did* find the documentation you were looking for [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/sigv4-query-string-auth.html).

Comment: yea, sorry I was in a bad mood.

Comment: Why is this documentation so much more complicated than the base64 - hmacsha1 url signing docs...

`Signature = URL-Encode( Base16( HMAC-SHA256( YourSecretAccessKeyID, UTF-8-Encoding-Of( StringToSign ) ) ) );`

Would be nice if that's all I had to do, do I really need to specify in the headers the kind of encryption? I'll assume Base64 w/ hmacsha1 is the default